# How to call a void function within if statement (Arduino)

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, arduino, void

I wrote a code supposed to do the following: if I press one button while in loop `void btnpress()`, the program is sent to another function `void blink2()`, and then one led goes on and after 3 secs the led should go off, and it should also return to `void btnpress()` again via `btnpress();`.
The issue is that if i press the button and release, the led goes on and stay still infinitely on, program seems not to execute the following last parts `digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);` and `btnpress();`.

```
const int btnpin = 9;
int btnstate = 0;
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long previousTime;
const long period = 3000;

// the setup
void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(btnpin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop
void loop()
{
    btnpress();
}

void btnpress()
{
    Serial.println("Press button");
    delay(500);
    btnstate = digitalRead(btnpin);
    if (btnstate == HIGH) {
        previousTime = millis();
        blink2();
    }
}

void blink2()
{
    if (currentTime - previousTime >= period) {
        Serial.println("Led on");
        previousTime = currentTime;
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // turn the LED on
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Led off");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        btnpress();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `currentTime` ever gets updated at all?

Comment: By the way, proper indentation would be an excellent idea.

Comment: @NateEldredge how can i do it?

Comment: Proper indentation is an _excellent idea_ if you want other people to read your code, which seems to be the situation you are in now.  This formatting hurts your chances of getting help.

Comment: Paste your code [here](http://format.krzaq.cc/), click "Format" and your code will get nicely formatted.

Comment: @cigien Stack overflow Error! Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Hmm, from the error message, it sounds like you just pasted your code without indenting it. A simpler option IMO, is to just add `\`\`\`` above and below the code. If you try to [edit] this question, you'll see that style of formatting being used. (another user already formatted this particular question, but make sure you see it, so you know what to do next time).

Comment: @cigien omg, now i see it, you guys were talking about the upper text that i took some parts of the code to explain the issue. But below i put the entire code within ```` so i thought it would not be necessary to format the upper parts.

Comment: Instead of `previousTime = millis();` it should be `currentTime = millis();`

Comment: @EyalK. no sir, i tried the way you told me, and the led does not even goes on.

Comment: `if (millis() - previousTime >= period) {`

Comment: `btnpress` calling `blink2` calling `btnpress` is a recursion, which is BAD. loops are done automatically, because `loop()` restarts when finished.

Comment: @datafiddler right, is there any way to do it without library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I press one button while in loop void btnpress(), the program is
> sent to another function void blink2(), and then one led goes on and
> after 3 secs the led should go off, and it should also return to void
> btnpress() again via btnpress();

According to this statement, I can suggest you to use the following code just to be sure if your functions are working according to your reqirement.

```
const int btnpin = 9;
int btnstate = 0;
//unsigned long currentTime;
//unsigned long previousTime;
const long period = 3000;

// the setup
void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(btnpin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop
void loop()
{
    btnpress();
}

void btnpress()
{
    Serial.println("Press button");
    delay(500);
    btnstate = digitalRead(btnpin);
    if (btnstate == HIGH) {
       // previousTime = millis();
        blink2();
    }
}

void blink2()
{
        Serial.println("Led on");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(3000);

        Serial.println("Led off");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        //btnpress(); It's already inside the Void loop            
}
```

If it's working well then function call is okay.
And there has no issue with "How to call a void function within if statement (Arduino)"

The problem may be inside your if statement,

```
if (currentTime - previousTime >= period) {
        Serial.println("Led on");
        previousTime = currentTime;
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // turn the LED on
    }
```

here, the currentTime is not Defined.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already found the solution. Anyway thanks for your contribution.